# Can a road dedicated to public use be un-dedicated?

Tags: united-states, north-carolina

I live in a neighborhood with private roads (USA, NC).  The roads were "dedicated" to the public use so that police, fire, trash, mail, etc. services could use them as needed.

Since the roads are private, the homeowners pay to maintain them. We have a couple of cul-de-sac's where future expansion was anticipated, but never happened and the way property has developed in the 30 years since this was all planned, they could not be used for expansion any more.

For these unused, but "dedicated" roads, can they be destroyed?  That is, could we dig up the asphalt and just let nature take it over?  And if we did that, would we have to "un-dedicate" the road first?

Also, if we wanted to make the roads fully private so we could restrict all traffic except homeowners and enumerated 3rd parties, that is, keep the general public out, but still allow utility and emergency services, can we un-dedicate the roads thus revoking the "dedicated for public use" clause?

The document is titled "Statement of Dedication of Streets and Roads for Public Use by an Individual" and was originally signed by the developer when the subdivision was cut.

The meat of the document (less signatures, notary space, etc.) is:

[image: road dedication]

Transcription:

> That we freely offer, grant, and dedicate to those who may purchase said property or any part thereof and to the general public, the use of the streets and roads shown on said plat of property for public use. That we freely offer, grant, and dedicate to those who may rent or purchase said property or any part thereof, and to their invitees or guests and to all government service vehicles and general service vehicles, such as fire, police, garbage, mail, etc. the use of the private drives as shown on said plat of property. That we shall be responsible for maintenance of the private drives as shown on said plat unless we require by recorded covenant running with the land the subsequent owners to be responsible.

Comment: that might depend on the dedication deed and county regulations.

Comment: I've not seen a dedication deed and the statement of dedication makes no mention of other documents.  How would i find if such a deed exists, and what if it doesnt?

Comment: Asking the county or municipality might be the most easy way. They *also* might be able to answer you if about the process to remove those constructions.

Comment: Thanks, Trish.  I wasn't sure there was even a path to an un-dedication... we had the impression that once dedicated it was permanent.